# Running a shell script that runs a python program, then an R program

Tags: python, r, bash, docker

I have a shell script that runs a Python program to pre-process some data and then runs an R program that does some long running task on it. I'm learning to use Docker and I've been running

```
FROM r-base:latest
FROM python
COPY . /usr/local/src/scripts
WORKDIR /usr/local/src/scripts
CMD ["./myscript.sh"]
```

To my understanding it does the following:

1. Get R
2. Get Python
3. Copy my current directory to `/usr/local/src/scripts`
4. Change directory to `/usr/local/src/scripts`
5. Run `./myscript.sh`

Inside `myscript.sh` I use the `R CMD ...` syntax for running my R script. However, when this docker image is run I get the following error:

```
./myscript.sh: line 8: R: command not found
```

This suggests that the script, when run inside the container, is not recognizing the R program. I can confirm that `./myscript.sh` works locally but I cannot expose any proprietary code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FROM command sets the base image that your Dockerfile builds on. You should only have one of these. After that, if you need additional tools that aren't in the base image, run commands that use platform-dependent package managers, such as

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    package-foo \
    package-bar
```

This would be for a Debian-based image, such as Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have a couple followups: 1. What's the default OS a Docker container uses? 2. Wouldn't it take a lot of space to have multiple Ubuntu installations if I had multiple images?

Comment: It's up to you which OS the container uses. A good default base image for many use cases is Ubuntu: FROM ubuntu

Comment: For your second question, these images take up a surprisingly small amount of space. Think of them as lobotomized images, they share a lot of resources with the host system (your computer) and are built from the ground up to be lightweight. Unlike with a VM, you won't even notice the space an image takes up in many cases. Don't forget to accept my answer if you think it has helped! :)